# Issue with nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I have very simple config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test.mydomain.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.test2.ru;
index  index.html;

    location / {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

When I am accessing to `test2.ru` `test.mydomain.ru` is opens. Why? `*.test2.ru` should handle any requests to `test2.ru`.

Can it be issue with DNS configuration? I have got follow settings:

`www A 164.138.29.xxx` for `test2.ru`;

and

`test A 164.138.29.xxx` for `test.mydomain.ru;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.test2.ru` will only match "***something***.test2.ru".

You'll need to add both `*.test2.ru` and `test2.ru` to the server_name configuration.

Edit: Apparently you can also do the following to match both with a single entry:

> A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to
>   match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name
>   “*.example.org”.

Also, for just `test2.ru` to work, you'll need to make sure `test2.ru` resolves to the IP address. The DNS records you show only cover `www.test2.ru` and `test.test2.ru`.